# dpfloat affects table caption spacing with floatrow

Tags: tables, spacing, captions, floatrow, dpfloat

I am trying to format two full-page tables such that they appear side-by-side on consecutive pages in a double-sided report.

Typically this is easy to achieve using [`dpfloat`](http://ctan.org/pkg/dpfloat) however, I have found that when used in conjunction with the [`floatrow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package the spacing between the table caption and table is much larger than it should be. I have tried using `\captionsetup{belowskip=-5cm}` (from the `caption` package) to adjust the spacing but this does not seem to have any influence.

Below is a MWE. If either `floatrow`or `dpfloat` are removed, the table captions return to their correct position. To date I have not had any issues when formatting figures using these two packages.

My question is: how can this behaviour be fixed and the captions correctly spaced above each table?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=normal, format=hang, labelfont=normal, labelsep=colon}

\usepackage{dpfloat}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multicol, multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable} 

\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{style=plaintop}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
%
\section{First Section}%
\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{table}%
\centering%
\begin{leftfullpage}%
  %\captionsetup{belowskip=-20pt}
  \caption{First table caption}%
  \begin{tabular}{lllll}%
      \toprule%
      First\tnote{(1)} & Second & Third & Fourth & Fifth\\%
      \midrule%
      1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\%
      6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\%
      11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15\\%
      \bottomrule%
  \end{tabular}%
\end{leftfullpage}%
\end{table}%

\begin{table}[p]%
\centering%
\begin{fullpage}%
\begin{threeparttable}%
  \caption{Second table caption}%
  \begin{tabular}{lllll}%
      \toprule%
      First\tnote{(1)} & Second & Third & Fourth & Fifth\\%
      \midrule%
      1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\%
      6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\%
      11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15\\%
      \bottomrule%
  \end{tabular}%
  %
  \begin{tablenotes}%
      \item [(1)] this is note 1%
  \end{tablenotes}%
\end{threeparttable}%
\end{fullpage}%
\end{table}%

\lipsum[1-4]%


\end{document}
```

Comment: What are you using `floatrow` for?

Comment: Though I'm not explicitly using `floatrow` in this MWE, in the actual document I use it to automatically adjust the width of captions to the figure/table width and to format sub-floats by way of the subfloatrow command. 

Also, in the actual document, the tables in question use the `sidewaystable` environment and their positioning on the page has to be tweaked using `\vspace` commands. The value of `\vspace` to be added depends on whether the table is on an odd or even page. Hence my desire to use `dpfloat`.